# PyQt5 Qtablewidget and connecting to buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I have created a Qtablewidget as a class, and add_button to add rows, a delete_button to remove rows from table down upwards. I would like to connect functions to buttons, but it doesn't work correctly. I have used getattr method to call the function, still does not work.

The table

[image]

to explain more, those scriptlines are giving attributte errors. when they are called by button.clicked.connect method.

```
add_button.clicked.connect(self._addrow)
delete_button.clicked.connect(self._removeItem)
```

The script is as below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, Qt


class loadtable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(loadtable, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setRowCount(1)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))   
        headertitle = ("A","B","C","D","E")
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headertitle)
        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 130)
        combox_lay = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_lay.addItems(["I","II"])
        self.setCellWidget(0, 4, combox_lay)


        self.cellChanged.connect(self._cellclicked)
        #self.cellChanged.connect(self._addrow)
        #self.cellDoubleClicked.connect(self._removerow)

    def _cellclicked(self):
        self.value = self.currentItem()
        self.value.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        #if self.value is not None:
           #return self.value.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)        

    def _addrow(self):
        rowcount = self.rowCount()
        print(rowcount)
        self.setRowCount(rowcount+1)
        combox_add = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_add.addItems(["I","II"])
        self.setCellWidget(rowcount, 4, combox_add)

    def _removerow(self):
        self.removeRow(1)


class thirdtabloads(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(thirdtabloads, self).__init__(parent)      
        table = loadtable()


        button_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        add_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add")
        add_button.clicked.connect(self._addrow)
        delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete")
        delete_button.clicked.connect(self._removeItem)
        button_layout.addWidget(add_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        button_layout.addWidget(delete_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)


        tablehbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        tablehbox.setContentsMargins(10,10,10,10)
        tablehbox.addWidget(table)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addLayout(button_layout, 0, 1)
        grid.addLayout(tablehbox, 0, 0)        



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = thirdtabloads()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: if you have n rows, when you press the delete_button button, which row should be deleted?

Comment: One option is to delete last row expect from first one. Second option I am thinking to select a row then delete it.

Comment: Decide please, do you want to delete the first or last row?

Comment: Last one being deleted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a row you must use `insertRow()`, to remove the last row use `removeRow()` and pass the last row and remember that the numbering starts from 0 so the last row is `self.rowCount() - 1.`

On the other hand, your connection is incorrect, I ask you: *Who owns the slot `_addrow()` and `_removerow()`?* belongs to LoadTable, so to access them we need an object of that class, ie `table._addrow` and `table._removerow`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class LoadTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoadTable, self).__init__(1, 5, parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))   
        headertitle = ("A","B","C","D","E")
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headertitle)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)

        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 130)

        combox_lay = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_lay.addItems(["I","II"])
        self.setCellWidget(0, 4, combox_lay)

        self.cellChanged.connect(self._cellclicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def _cellclicked(self, r, c):
        it = self.item(r, c)
        it.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _addrow(self):
        rowcount = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(rowcount)
        combox_add = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_add.addItems(["I","II"])
        self.setCellWidget(rowcount, 4, combox_add)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _removerow(self):
        if self.rowCount() > 0:
            self.removeRow(self.rowCount()-1)


class ThirdTabLoads(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThirdTabLoads, self).__init__(parent)    

        table = LoadTable()

        add_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add")
        add_button.clicked.connect(table._addrow)

        delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete")
        delete_button.clicked.connect(table._removerow)

        button_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addWidget(add_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        button_layout.addWidget(delete_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)


        tablehbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        tablehbox.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        tablehbox.addWidget(table)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addLayout(button_layout, 0, 1)
        grid.addLayout(tablehbox, 0, 0)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ThirdTabLoads()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Great :) I have a question regarding your answer, what does it mean or do this 1, 5 number? super(LoadTable, self).__init__(1, 5, parent)

Comment: I could see, that I just lack @QtCore.pyqtSlot() in my question. then it would solve the problem. But you rewrite in more professional way.Thanks this is third time you help me. :)

Comment: @ZarKha  QTableWidget you have several constructors, among them the following: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#QTableWidget-1, in that constructor you can indicate the number of initial rows and columns, so that 1 and 5 equals: `self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setRowCount(1)`

Comment: @ZarKha That is an improvement, not the solution, analyze the differences and my explanation. On the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, that's the best way to thank, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that's the best way to thank.

Comment: I appreciate much your improvement.